# Have a complete site search work without a database

Tags: html

Hi I have made a search box on my home page but I'm trying to make it search my whole site and look for the title of a page. I have been stuck for a couple of weeks and I need help.

Comment: You can implement one of those crappy google search boxes. I think this is the doc on it: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1737334?hl=en - you have no access to server side? Just front end html?

Comment: You've been stuck on this for a *couple of weeks*?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with HTML only. I recommend you to use PHP to do it. If you don't want to use a database you can search your files. You might be also interested in [Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/)

Comment: I think you could do it client side only if you were willing to put an extreme amount of effort into maintaining static lists in a json object and calling results from that using javascript. Otherwise, yeah - html only? Not only does it sound like you couldn't do it, but it's archaic to have an html limitation that does not include js these days

Comment: Hi thanks but I have tried the pup and I can't find a answer. Does anyone have any code they might want to share